# C++ Segmentation_Fault With Set

Tags: c++, set

I'm relatively new to c++, and trying to understand why my following code is recieving `segmentation fault`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

set<int> S;

int main(){
    S.insert(1);

    auto it = S.lower_bound(1);
    cout << *it << endl;
    cout << (it-- == S.begin()) << endl;
}
```

1. Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't c++ allow you to decrement your iterator, as long as your iterator is within `S.begin()` to `S.end()`, inclusive?
2. Why does it work to test an iterator for `S.begin()` for it to be out of bounds? Isn't the element `S.begin()` also a valid element inside set `S`?

Comment: It makes no sense to decrement the begin iterator, thus this is UB.

Comment: 1. In contrast to the one-past-the-end iterator, i.e. `end()`, there is no one-before-the-beginning iterator. (Similarly, trying to get a pointer to the (imaginary) element before the first element of an array, `&the_array[-1]`, is undefined.) 2. What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: It's possible you're remembering Java's iterators, where they have an analogous before-the-beginning state instead of a past-the-end one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [c++ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator)

> The begin iterator is not decrementable and the behavior is undefined if --container.begin() is evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set states that `std::set` uses a biderectional iterator. So decrementing is possible.

However since you only have one element in the set, `S.lower_bound(1)` will return `S.begin()`. You are trying to move the iterator to an element before the very first element in the set (the iterator does not loop from start to end).